# Cardview shadow looks different when inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-scrollview, android-elevation

I stumbled upon something weird. I am using the same `CardView` component in more than one place in my app, all with the same elevation (3dp), and they all looks the same. However, for one scenario I need to embed the `CardView` inside a `ScrollView`. I didn't change anything in the `CardView` configuration, but the shadow now looks different.

This is my layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipChildren="false"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:scrollbars="none">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="3dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <!-- some other views-->

     </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</ScrollView>
```

In the picture below you can see on the right the `CardView` and on the left the two shadows: on the top the shadow generated by the `CardView` alone, on the bottom the one generated when the `CardView` is inside a `ScrollView`. As you can see the second one appears darker and thicker.

NOTE: The background color (#FAFAFA) is the same in both scenario.

[image]

Comment: Try using `com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView` from design library and check if issue persist.

Comment: @JeelVankhede just tried, with the exact same result.

Answer (score 0):

For both cases, I would check the following properties as it could contribute to the difference you're seeing:

- `getTranslationZ()`
- `getElevation()`
- `getOutlineAmbientShadowColor()` (this is only valid in API 28+)
- `getOutlineSpotShadowColor()` (this is only valid in API 28+)

Plus, checking Layout inspector to see if there's any view that could affect to the rendering.

Also, [this article](https://blog.usejournal.com/playing-with-elevation-in-android-91af4f3be596) from Sebastiano Poggi could be of help.

Comment: The values are the same for both scenario. Except the last two cause I am using API 26 device.

Comment: Could you check it in a 28+ device (or emulator) and check if it changes anything and if the values for the Outline*ShadowColor properties are the same. From what I know those properties already existed before (I guess from 21), is only that they where not accessible (easily?).